# Insert image in Excel using xlwt in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, xlwt

I tried:

> sheetLoopParam.insert_bitmap(os.path.abspath("static/PLL_diagram2_small.bmp"), 12, 0)

but it says:

> IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\Users\rest_of_path\static\PLL_diagram2_small.bmp'

The path it displays *is* correct, I don't understand why it says it can't access it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, more or less. I put the image in the app's root directory instead of inside the static directory, seems to like that ok.

Like this:

> sheetLoopParam.insert_bitmap(os.path.abspath("**PLL_diagram2_small.bmp**"), 12, 0)

instead of like this:

> sheetLoopParam.insert_bitmap(os.path.abspath("**static/PLL_diagram2_small.bmp**"), 12, 0)

I just need to insert the one image so that works ok.